# How to show the default beautiful popup message in ubuntu using python?

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, popup, gnome

http://tinypic.com/r/5dv7kj/7
How can i show the message like in the picture(top right)?

I'm new to linux and now tring to use pygtk to make a client application to show/popup some random hint/mems.

Using traditional winodw is OK,but this one is much more friendly to me.I have tried scanning through the pygtk guide but still missing the solution.Other

Is there any body could give me some hint?Any python GUI libs are also OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an Ubuntu specific thing called [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD). There are examples of programming for it [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#Layout%20cases%20%28with%20examples%20in%20C,%20Python%20and%20C#%29).

Answer (score 5):

Quick and Dirty codes in python

```
import pynotify

# Only Text Notification
pynotify.init('Basic')
pynotify.Notification("Title", "simple text").show()


# Lets try with an image
pynotify.init('Image')
## Use absolute Path of the photo
pynotify.Notification("Title", "My Photo here!!", "/home/nafis/Pictures/me.png").show()

# Try Markup 
pynotify.init("markup") ## all smallerCase "markup"
# but in parameter, first letter capital  
pynotify.Notification("Markup", 
  '''
  <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>, <u>underline</u>
  and even <a href="http://google.com">links</a> are supported!
  '''
).show()
```

Also You can use it from shell (I use lubuntu, it works here.)

```
#!/bin/bash
### try it in terminal

notify-send -t 900 "Title" "Message"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple method without any additional packages.
you can execute commands via os.system.

```
import os

def message(title, message):
  os.system(f"notify-send '{title}' '{message}'")

message("Title", "Im message")
```

Comment: It seems like there should be single-quotes around `{title}` and `{message}`, i..e `os.system(f"notify-send '{title}' '{message}'")`.

Comment: yes bro, if the message or title has more than one word then there should be quotes, post edited, thank you